# Visual Studio Load Test Socket Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

When running a Visual Studio Load Test I'm seeing lost of Socket Exceptotion below:

> *at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean
>   connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress&
>   address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Exception& exception)*

Could someone please help me understand on what's the cause of above and whether the response time will go up as a result of this (assuming the request will wait a while).

Thanks.

Comment: You've truncated the exception message... that's just the stack trace. Give us the entire exception please.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the Network emulation that is not correctly configured or there are some cause that are making it behave wrong. You can check this simply trying  to run a test on a single network.

[How can I verify that network emulation is working](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182594.aspx#createrunloadtest_qa_networktypes) (Look in the Q&A section)